# Connection question for Renology - order and possible converter needed?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, solar-energy

I bought a Renology 100w solar panel with charge controller - and I see in the controller instructions booklet, "Never connect the solar panel array to the controller without a battery. Battery must be connected first. This may cause a dangerous occurrence where the controller would experience a high open circuit voltage at the terminals."

However the solar panel connections for the controller included (looks like a [MC4 by this page](https://www.cedgreentech.com/article/types-solar-connectors-and-couplers)) show stop, do not disconnect under load. So, which is it, if I set up a portable system I cannot pack it up by unplugging the solar panel from the controller, I cannot pack up by unplugging the battery from the controller either?

What's more, I see [the pack I have](https://www.bioennopower.com/products/copy-of-renewable-power-pack-bpp-160?variant=32174955266122) has an input of 15v, measured on the adapters and this probably will not work seeing the voltage marked 12v on the controller... would that charge it not at all or, very slowly? Would just a dc-dc converter 12v to 15v, to plug be all that's necessary in this case?

Comment: can you turn off the charge controller? ... if in boubt, cover the panel, then disconnect ... the power pack has its own charge controller ... connect the panel directly

Comment: I don't think it has its own controller? At least it has a separate output plug to Anderson converter to make the battery's internal 9-12v a consistent 13v for ham radio equipment.